# Excel: Conditional Formatting with dynamic row reference

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

I would like to use a certain conditional formatting for a larger table.

The table is set up in a way that **all headers and formulas repeat in fixed intervals**.
- Row 2 contains the headers which get repeated every 31 rows, so again in row 33, 64, 95 etc.
- Rows 3:32 contain formulas which get repeated the same way, so again in rows 34:63, 65:94 etc.

I would like to have just one conditional formatting that can be applied to each of these blocks and always references a block's header row (i.e. rows 2, 33, 64 etc).

**For the first block I can achieve this with the following formula but this doesn't work if applied to the other blocks:**

```
 =AND(($D2<>""),(E$2<>"x"))
```

**In order to adapt it for the other blocks, I tried to create a dynamic reference to the header rows instead of the fixed E$2 but this also doesn't work:**

```
 =AND(($D2<>""),(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",""),ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/30,0) +2))<>"x"))
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Many thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Construct the formula in a worksheet cell before you try it in a conditional format. When the formula is in a worksheet cell, you can step through it with the Evaluate Formula tool. There you can see which part of the formula does not work. Your setup is too complex to recreate for testing, so, unless you post a sample file (on OneDrive or DropBox), it will be hard to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have misunderstood (hence might be premature to explain what is wrong at present) but for conditionally formatting each 31st row starting at Row2 (ie just the headers for each block) please select as many columns as are relevant and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MOD(ROW(),31)=2
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

To see better what the above contributes you may want to clear all CF from the sheet first.

This merely triggers when the remainder from dividing the row number by 31 is `2`.